# jQuery - Assigning click events to images added by an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image-gallery

I'm in the process of attempting to build a jQuery based image gallery using an array to host the image thumbs.  I have been successful at getting the images to render in a row, but am having difficulties figuring out a solution around how to assign a unique click event to each image within the array.

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbCont"></div>
```

jQuery/JS:

```
var thumbImgArray = ["http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-11/256/thumbs-up.png", "http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-11/256/thumbs-up-medium-skin-tone.png", "http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-11/256/thumbs-up-medium-skin-tone.png"]


var $div = $('#thumbCont');
$.each(thumbImgArray, function(i, val) {
        $("<img />").attr("src", val).appendTo($div).css({float: "left", width: "196px", height: "196px", marginRight: "4px", border: "2px solid white", cursor: "pointer"});
 });
```

Here is my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/themandoz/y31oLjrL/15/).

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding `onclick` event handler while creating the `img` tag

```js
var thumbImgArray = ["http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-11/256/thumbs-up.png", "http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-11/256/thumbs-up-medium-skin-tone.png", "http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-11/256/thumbs-up-medium-skin-tone.png"]


var $div = $('#thumbCont');
$.each(thumbImgArray, function(i, val) {

  $("<img id='img_" + i + "' onclick='test(this.id)'/>").attr("src", val).appendTo($div).css({
    float: "left",
    width: "196px",
    height: "196px",
    marginRight: "4px",
    border: "2px solid white",
    cursor: "pointer"
  });
});

function test(imgId) {
  console.log(imgId)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbCont"></div>
```